# Bind expand click event in jstree

Tags: jquery, jstree

In jsTree when I click the expand icon(+), I catch the "click.jstree" event and  get the message "expand clicked!", on the other hand when I click in a node I expect just the "node clicked!" message.. gets it first but then prompt "expand clicked!" msg too..

```
$('#tree_2').jstree({..})
.bind('click.jstree', function (e, datap) {
    alert("expand icon! clicked");

}).bind('select_node.jstree', function (e, datap) {
    alert("node clicked");
});
```

As you guess when I click to node, both of these functions are trigged but I need one trigger for this event just 'select_node.jstree' or etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the ideal solution, but you can do this:

```
$('#tree_2').jstree({..})
.bind('click.jstree', function (e, datap) {
    treeClicked(e, datap);

}).bind('select_node.jstree', function (e, datap) {
    treeClicked(e, datap);
});

function treeClicked(e, datap) {
    alert("tree clicked");
}
```

Hope it helped :)